# c++ : How to make a specific binary (executable) for each trait?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am working on a project that has a lot of trait types. If I compile every trait in the same code base, the released binary would be quite big.

I am thinking about to use macro to build a binary for each specific trait --- from a business logic perspective, this makes perfect sense.

However, I realized that, if I want to cut down the code base, I need to have this long if/elif pile at the end of each template cpp file. This sounds like a very tedious thing to do.

I am wondering if you have encountered this kind of problem before, what's the most neat solution here?

```
#include "MyTraits.hpp"
#include "Runner.hpp"
int main(){
    #if defined USE_TRAIT_1
    Runner<Trait1> a;
    #elif defined USE_TRAIT_2
    Runner<Trait2> a;
    #elif defined USE_TRAIT_3
    Runner<Trait3> a;
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would just have 5 different main_<trait> cpp files, each of which would define a set of typedefs and than call a common templated  function.

Comment: your solution looks good to me. If you have a ton of them maybe you could write a script to parse your code base and generate the main function and makefile(or similar). You could also maybe do `Runner<USE_TRAIT> where USE_TRAIT is in your make file

Comment: Rather than the specific way you did it, it may be easier to instead do `Runner<TRAIT> a;` and instead of just compiling with `-DUSE_TRAIT_1`, you'd do `-DTRAIT=Trait1` (define appropriately for whatever build system you are using)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that my answer will address the root cause of the problem. But the proposed solution may at least look a bit more "neat".

The basic idea behind the [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45447650/c-how-to-make-a-specific-binary-executable-for-each-trait#comment77857369_45447650) by @JeffCharter makes sense, but I don't like the idea of embedding the code (in this case type names) into the makefile. So I elaborated on it a bit, with the following goals in mind:

- Make the contents of main() short and easy to understand
- Avoid polluting the makefile
- Avoid the macro usage to the most possible extent

I ended up with the following solution which requires a single numeric macro which can be defined in the makefile. Be aware that it uses C++17's `constexpr if`, so in case you find it useful make sure your compiler supports it.

```
constexpr int traitID = TRAIT_ID; // TRAIT_ID is a macro defined somewhere else.

template <typename T>
struct Wrapped // helper struct
{
    using Type = T;
};

auto trait()
{
    // Although it may look not that different from macros, the main difference
    // is that here all the code below gets compiled.
    if constexpr (traitID == 1)
        return Wrapped<Trait1>{};
    else if constexpr (traitID == 2)
        return Wrapped<Trait2>{};
    else if constexpr (traitID == 3)
        return Wrapped<Trait3>{};
    // add more cases if necessary
}

int main() // the contents of 'main' seems to have become more readable
{
    using Trait = decltype(trait())::Type;
    Runner<Trait> a;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, here's [a live example at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67ebb84607019e32).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicity instanciate templates in specific compilation units you should use the `extern template` keyword.

```
// Runner.hpp
//define your template class
template <class runner_trait>
class Runner {
...
};

//This tells the compiler to not instanciate the template,
// if it is encounterd, but link to it from a compilation unit.
// If it is not found, you will get a linker errer.
extern template Runner<Trait1>;
extern template Runner<Trait2>;
extern template Runner<Trait3>;
```

---

```
Runner_trait1.cpp

// the template class keyword tell the compiler to instanciate the template in this compilation unit.
template class Runner<Trait1>;

// The files for Runner_trait2.cpp and  Runner_trait3.cpp look identical,
// except for the trait after Runner
```